# How to Implement Singleton class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

I'm new to swift programming and please tell me how to implement singleton class in swift with code.

in obj-c I Know

```
+ (id)sharedManager {
   static MediaModel *sharedMyManager = nil;
   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
      sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
   });
   return sharedMyManager;
}
```

How is it in swift

Comment: Follow this url for singleton class http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80246/swift-1-2-singleton-implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's so simple in Swift:

```
class YourClass {
    static let sharedInstance = YourClass()
}
```

and to use it:

```
YourClass.sharedInstance
```

Comment: Thanks Boss! Working Now

Answer (score 1):

Swift is lot smarter than Obj-C about singleton class. You can declare like this;

```
final class MediaModel: NSObject {

    static let sharedMyManager = MediaModel()

    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Then call it;

```
let sharedManager = MediaModel.sharedMyManager
```